# Input datalist covers mobile keyboard (html)

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

**example**

```
<datalist id='example'>
       {
           props.list.map(data => <option value={props.data} />) // 1000 items
       }
</datalist>

<input list='example' type='text' />
```

When the input is clicked, the datalist is shown but it covers the keyboard, I tried setting a max height but that does not work, is there any way to fix this without making a custom dropdown?